# Wacom DTU-1031X (how to run as display)

Tags: tablet, wacom

I've got graphic tablet Wacom DTU-1031X, which has its own lcd display. Under Windows it works as additional display, but under Ubuntu only as classic non-display tablet. Is there any solution to run it under linux?

```
[63888.210502] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[63888.358753] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2412, bcdDevice= b.b2
[63888.358759] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[63888.360571] hub 2-3:1.0: USB hub found
[63888.361191] hub 2-3:1.0: 2 ports detected
[63888.646459] usb 2-3.1: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[63888.748725] usb 2-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0711, idProduct=520e, bcdDevice= 0.01
[63888.748730] usb 2-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=0
[63888.748733] usb 2-3.1: Product: DTU-1031X
[63888.748736] usb 2-3.1: Manufacturer: MCT
[63888.830516] usb 2-3.2: new full-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[63888.934150] usb 2-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=032f, bcdDevice= 1.01
[63888.934156] usb 2-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[63888.934159] usb 2-3.2: Product: DTU-1031X
[63888.934162] usb 2-3.2: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
[63888.934165] usb 2-3.2: SerialNumber: 7BZQ000938
[63888.940964] input: Wacom DTU1031X Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.2/2-3.2:1.0/0003:056A:032F.0006/input/input36
[63888.998865] wacom 0003:056A:032F.0006: hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Wacom Co.,Ltd. DTU-1031X] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.2/input0
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [Displaylink](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads). Unzip the download, make it executable and run it as sudo. Reboot.

After that, your tablet display should be recognized as a new monitor. In my case, I ran into many bugs in Kubuntu 20.04 (screen tearing, freezes, black screen...) that I uninstalled using `sudo displaylink-installer uninstall`.

I hope that this won't be your case. If you can, tell me your experience in a comment.